# 301 Redirect from Root to Subfolder for some URLs

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect, root

I had to move a social networking script from my root (domain.com) to a subfolder (domain.com/folder).  I did this because I created a new homepage and wanted the social script to be in the subfolder as a side page.

With that in mind, most of my pages are now domain.com/folder/page.htm instead of domain.com/page.htm.

I have read ways to 301 redirect all pages from domain.com to /folder but my issue is that I don't want my new homepage to redirect as well.  Is there any way I can make the pages in /folder redirect to the subfolder domain, while leaving all the files in the root not being redirected?

Thanks all!

Comment: and when a file exists in both folders?

Comment: index.php exists in both so that may be an issue, however one is in root and one is in /subfolder so I'm hoping there is a way to make it work in the htaccess file. Besides index.php I can't think of any other files that will be the same.